# Buffering on 2 ms ping with 49 Mbps download and upload speeds

Tags: networking, router, internet, tv

> **UPDATE:** Resolved this issue and added an answer. The issue is specific to some Sony Android TVs.

I have this unfathomable issue with my internet of late where I get intermittent buffering and connection issues while the speed test keeps showing peak performance.

**Connection details:** 60 Mbps plan (both down and up), fiber optic connection. N1200 router with both 2.4 and 5 GHz bands (TP-Link Archer A6). I have a 2 room apartment, no mesh network.

At any given time, a maximum of 5 devices are connected: 3 phones, a TV, and a laptop. Of them, only one or two would actually be pulling content at a time. Most devices are on the 5 GHz network except the laptops.

**Issues I'm facing:**

- Buffering on videos. On laptops, phones and the TV. This happens on streaming services, YouTube, and news apps
- Sudden stream quality drops. From 4K to 144p in an instant
- On the computers and phones, the first load of any site takes noticeably longer. By first load I mean things starting to show up on the screen from the time I hit enter. About 5-6 seconds, sometimes 10 or more. However, once it does start to load, it gets complete in an instant. One thing that I have noticed helps is to turn off wifi and use mobile data to begin the site load, and then it works snappily once I'm back on wifi.

**What speed test says:** ping around 2-3 ms, jitter 1 ms, speeds around 40-60 for download, 50-60 for upload. This is consistent across multiple tests done at the exact time as I'm facing the issues.

What other factors could this be due to? I'm out of ideas and I want to be knowledgeable enough while talking with the ISP.

With this exact setup, I have had better performance on a 25 Mbps plan with a different ISP.

Comment: What DNS servers are you using (i.e. what does each computer report as currently being used in 'ipconfig /all', and what does your router show as well), and does nslookup return results quickly from _each_ of them (`nslookup google.com <server>`)? Do your computers report IPv6 being available (i.e. an IPv6 address that starts with "2xxx:"), and if so, can you `ping -4` _and_ `ping -6` sites like google.com or youtube.com?

Comment: I would also try doing speed tests using fast.com
They use data from Netflix servers, so it looks to the ISP that it is normal internet use, and not a speed test. Some ISPs have been known to prioritise traffic when you do a speed test and give you a false reading.

Comment: @user1686 I use Cloudflare as primary and Google DNS as secondany DNS for my laptop nslookup does return results quickly for both of them. I do not have IPv6 available. The modem does have a different DNS server defined by the ISP, which also returns result quckly

Comment: @Randomhero Tried fast.com, it is showing similar results, 40 to 60 Mbps download, 40 Mbps upload. Latency is 2 ms unloaded and 36 to 90 ms loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue. This is something unique to some Sony Android TVs including mine.
The TV does not play nice with Wi-Fi networks which have the same SSID (name) for both the 2.4 GHz and 5GHz bands. It has some issue maintaining a stable connection with the router in this configuration.
The solution is to have different SSIDs for the different bands in the router, and connect the TV to only one of them. My issue has been resolved now.

Answer (score 2):

Thet appear to be multiple issues at play.

DNS issues do not affect buffering, and only affect speed when resolving the domain into an IP address.  It dies sound like this was one issue which has been solved.

Buffering implies lack of available bandwidth between you and the target site. This could be due to congestion anywhere on the route or packet shaping.  It is not unheard of for ISP's to limit traffic to some sites and not others (either deliberately using rate limiting  or due to congested paths).    I expect this is the cause of your buffering.  Diagnosing it can be very trick (especially because, at least in my experience, ISP's lie) - but using something like WinMTR while streaming MAY give you some indication where on the path the issue is occuring, and using a VPN can also sometimes provide hints - but you need to understand the totality of what you are looking at to come to any firm conclusions.

There are other possibilites as well - eg mtu issues, or congestion caused by WIFI are not unheard of.